# Задача написать JavaScript-функцию, которая разместит блоки с текстом как газетные колонки

Tags: javascript

Формат ввода
Реализуйте функцию renderWaterfall. На вход она должна принимать следующие параметры:

rootNode: элемент в котором находятся объявления (HTMLDivElement) columnCount: количество колонок (number) elementGap: расстояние между колонками, а также элементами по-вертикали (number)

Пример rootNode:

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="el">У каждого объявления есть свои стили</div>
  <div class="el">Их не нужно менять</div>
  <div class="el">Каждое объявление должно быть свободным по высоте</div>
  <div class="el">А вот ширину нужно будет выставить</div>
  <div class="el">Ширину элемента root, при необходимости вы можете определить, но в тестах она может быть разная</div>
</div>
```

Формат вывода
При вызове в контексте html-страницы функция renderWaterfall должна расположить DOM-элементы объявлений так, чтобы они разместились в columnsCount колонок, а расстояние между ними составляло elementGap. Каждый следующий элемент нужно помещать в ту колонку, высота которой меньше остальных. При равных наименьших высотах элемент помещается в первую колонку слева.

Например:

```
function renderWaterfall(rootNode, columnCount, elementGap) {
...
```

}
Примечания
Не удаляйте существующие классы элементов. Вы можете изменять ширину объявлений, но высота должна быть зависимой от контента. Можно добавлять свои дополнительные элементы для структурирования.

Comment: Ага, а чем вопрос? что сами сделали? Или просто скинули условие, в надежде, что кто-то решит?

Comment: @Evgenii Это просто проверка наших возможностей :) Прикольное тестовое задание. Нет вопроса - значит нет ответа. Просто можно скопиравть условие и решить самому где-то :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой ход мыслей. Но осталась не решена задача : Каждый следующий элемент нужно помещать в ту колонку, высота которой меньше остальных.

```
function renderWaterfall(rootNode, columnCount, elementGap) {
const el = document.querySelectorAll(".el");
percent = (100 / columnCount - 10) + '%'
rootNode.style.display = 'flex'
rootNode.style.flex = '1 1 auto'
rootNode.style.justifyContent = 'space-between';
rootNode.style.flexWrap = 'wrap'
el.forEach(element => {
    element.style.flexShrink = '0';
    element.style.width = "calc(1/" + columnCount + "*100% - (1 - 1/3)*" + elementGap + "px" + ")";
    element.style.marginBottom = String(elementGap) + 'px'
});
```

}

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! раз это не ответ, то стоило опубликовать это как комментарий. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос